# STL: the transform and copy function questions in c++

Tags: c++, string, stl, copy, transform

As I'm testing in the Unitest. The transform function can't assign the new value into result. And the copy function can't compile. Can someone help me to figure out what's happening there?

Thank you so much !

```
// Include standard library headers
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <ostream>
using std::ostream;

#include <sstream>
using std::stringstream;

#include <string>
using std::string;

// Include test headers
#include "TestFramework.h"
#include "UnitTest.h"

// *************** Start the Unit test methods below *******************

void Hw1UnitTest::Initialize(ostream &out)
{
    TestFramework::Initialize(&out);
}

void Hw1UnitTest::DisplaySummary()
{
    TestFramework::DisplaySummary();
}
int current = 0;
int UniNumber() {return ++current;}

void Hw1UnitTest::TestDeque()
{
    TestFramework::BeginTest("Test Deque");

    deque<int> myDeck;
    int init = 0;
    int result;
    generate_n(back_inserter(myDeck), 10, UniNumber);

    result = accumulate(myDeck.begin(), myDeck.end(), init);

    TEST_ASSERT(55 == result);

    TestFramework::EndTest();
}

int toUpperCase(int lower) { return toupper(lower); }

void Hw1UnitTest::TestString()
{
    TestFramework::BeginTest("Test String");

    string sample = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string result;
    // problem there's no return value to the result string ****************
    transform(sample.begin(), sample.end(), result.begin(), toUpperCase);

    TEST_ASSERT("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" == result);

    TestFramework::EndTest();
}

bool IsEven (int i) { return (i%2) == 0; }

void Hw1UnitTest::TestVector()
{
    TestFramework::BeginTest("Test Vector");

    int sample[] = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    vector<int> vector0 (sample, (sample + 10));
    vector<int>::iterator bound;
    bound = std::partition (vector0.begin(), vector0.end(), IsEven);
    sort(vector0.begin(), vector0.begin() + 5);
    sort(vector0.begin() + 5, vector0.end());

    ostringstream os;
    // problem here, can not do copy **************
    copy(vector0.begin(), vector0.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(os));

    TEST_ASSERT("24681013579" == os.str());

    TestFramework::EndTest();
}
```

Comment: please show the errors that compiler reported, and toUpperCase function

Comment: Don't `#include` any headers after using `using` to bring new (potentially very common and/or short!) identifies into the global namespace.

Comment: Please post error information for a better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this statement

```
copy(vector0.begin(), vector0.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(os));
```

to

```
copy(vector0.begin(), vector0.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(os));
```

Here the problem is that the value type of the vector iterator is int while you are trying to assign it to an object of type std::string because the value type of the ostream iterators is specified by you as std::string.

And also change

```
string sample = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string result;
// problem there's no return value to the result string ****************
transform(sample.begin(), sample.end(), result.begin(), toUpperCase);
```

to

```
string sample = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string result;
// problem there's no return value to the result string ****************
transform(sample.begin(), sample.end(), std::back_inserter( result ), toUpperCase);
```

The problem is that object `result` is empty and you may not use iterator `begin` to enter new elements.
You could use your code

```
string sample = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string result;
// problem there's no return value to the result string ****************
transform(sample.begin(), sample.end(), result.begin(), toUpperCase);
```

if you would define result as

```
string sample = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string result( sample.size() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `std::transform()` doesn't work because the destination needs to be large enough to receive the output and your destination is an *empty string*. You can use a `std::back_inserter` so the algorithm will `push_back()` new values to the destination.

Change

```
transform(sample.begin(), sample.end(), result.begin(), toUpperCase);
```

to

```
transform(sample.begin(), sample.end(), back_inserter(result), toUpperCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the copy statement

```
copy( vector0.begin(), vector0.end(), ostream_iterator<string>( os));
```

you have to indicate for the ostream_iterator what is the underlying type over which it iterates. Since `vector0` contains `int`s this should read:

```
copy( vector0.begin(), vector0.end(), ostream_iterator<int>( os));
```

Regarding `std::transform`, `result` is empty, so you have to preallocate the space for string:

```
string sample = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string result( sample.size());
transform( sample.begin(), sample.end(), result.begin(), toUpperCase);
```

or use `back_inserter` to add elements into string that has not a space for elements in the moment

```
transform( sample.begin(), sample.end(), back_inserter(result), toUpperCase);
```

But the problem may be also related to the `toUpperCase` function, which implementation you didn't show.